# SQLAlchemy MissingGreenlet Error When Accessing User Object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm encountering an issue in my FastAPI application when trying to access the user.password attribute. Here's a summary of the problem:

I'm using SQLAlchemy with an asynchronous MySQL database.
I've defined a User model with a password field in my application.
I'm trying to verify a user's password during the login process.
However, when I try to access user.password, I encounter the following error:

sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?

I've ensured that the user object is retrieved from the database, and I can print the user object successfully before the password verification step.

Here's the relevant code:

```
async def login(request: LoginSchema):
    user = await UserRepository.find_by_email(request.email)

    if user and pwd_context.verify(request.password, user.password):
        # ... (token generation and response)
```

My database session setup and UserRepository are as follows:

````
# UserRepository
class UserRepository(BaseRepo):
    model = User

    @staticmethod
    async def find_by_email(email: str):
        qry = select(User).where(User.email == email)
        return (await db.execute(qry)).scalar_one_or_none()
    
    ```
````

#db session

class DatabaseSession:
def **init**(self):
self.session = None
self.engine = None

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    return getattr(self.session, item)

def init(self):
    self.engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, future=True, echo=True)
    self.session = async_sessionmaker(self.engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)()

async def create_all(self):
    async with self.engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```

db = DatabaseSession()
`

I suspect that this issue may be related to SQLAlchemy's lazy loading mechanism. Could someone provide insights into what might be causing this error and how I can access the user.password attribute without triggering this exception?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I realized in my models, the password field used the "deferred" keyword, in SQLAlchemy it's used to delay the loading of certain columns, which can be useful for optimizing database queries, especially when dealing with large datasets. However, in my case, using "deferred" on the password column caused unexpected behavior.

When I tried to access the "user.password" attribute, it triggered a database query because the password column was not loaded into memory until that point.

To resolve this issue, I removed the "deferred" keyword from the password column definition in my User model to ensure that the password column is loaded immediately when the User object is queried from the database, eliminating the greenlet spawn error.